# data missing only in a single column after updating mysql table

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, missing-data

I'm new to jsp servlets. I'm doing a jsp,servlet CRUD project with eclipse and mysql. Insert,Delete operations are ok but when I updating the data on a row of the employee table, data of the userName column are missing. It only occures when updating a column. I tried to manually update the userName column but no success. Here are images of after inserting and updating done.

[inserting a new row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDDW9.png)

[updating the first name as "Alan"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NUB.png)

update query

```
public static int update(Emp m){
int status=0;
try{
    Connection con=getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("update employee set fname=?,lname=?,userName=?,passwrd=?,age=?,gender=?,address=?,contactNo=?,email=?,jobType=?,department=?,qualifics=?,salary=?,hireDate=? where id=?");
    ps.setString(1,m.getFname());
    ps.setString(2,m.getLname());
    ps.setString(3,m.getUserName());
    ps.setString(4,m.getPasswrd());
    ps.setInt(5,m.getAge());
    ps.setString(6,m.getGender());
    ps.setString(7,m.getAddress());
    ps.setString(8,m.getContactNo());
    ps.setString(9,m.getEmail());
    ps.setString(10,m.getJobType());
    ps.setString(11,m.getDepartment());
    ps.setString(12,m.getQualifics());
    ps.setDouble(13,m.getSalary());
    ps.setString(14,m.getHireDate());
    ps.setInt(15,m.getId());

    status=ps.executeUpdate();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }

return status;}
```

retrieve data from the database

```
public static List<Emp> getAllRecords(){
List<Emp> list=new ArrayList<Emp>();

try{
    Connection con=getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        Emp m=new Emp();
        m.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        m.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
        m.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
        m.setUserName(rs.getString("userName"));
        m.setPasswrd(rs.getString("passwrd"));
        m.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
        m.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
        m.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
        m.setContactNo(rs.getString("contactNo"));
        m.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        m.setJobType(rs.getString("jobType"));
        m.setDepartment(rs.getString("department"));
        m.setQualifics(rs.getString("qualifics"));
        m.setSalary(rs.getDouble("salary"));
        m.setHireDate(rs.getString("hireDate"));

        list.add(m);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }
return list;}
```

get data by id

```
public static Emp getRecordById(int id){
Emp m=null;
try{
    Connection con=getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id=?");
    ps.setInt(1,id);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        m=new Emp();
        m.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        m.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
        m.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
        m.setUserName(rs.getString("userName"));
        m.setPasswrd(rs.getString("passwrd"));
        m.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
        m.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
        m.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
        m.setContactNo(rs.getString("contactNo"));
        m.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        m.setJobType(rs.getString("jobType"));
        m.setDepartment(rs.getString("department"));
        m.setQualifics(rs.getString("qualifics"));
        m.setSalary(rs.getDouble("salary"));
        m.setHireDate(rs.getString("hireDate"));
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }

return m;}
```

images for the viewtable.jsp

[import Empdb.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cdGx.png)

[table headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1JfQ.png)

[get table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L1QO.png)

what should I do?
Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Are you fetching the list again, after update the record.  OR refresh the Employee list page after update.

Comment: The action of the edit user form is set to the viewusers.jsp (table). Here is a screenshot of the edit form https://prnt.sc/setc3t  After updating the records the table displays again with updated data. Other columns are updating normally. I don't have any other problems with the project. Only userName column has the problem that I cant find, I  created a new project and copy/paste all the files into it but the problem is still there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can u share the code on git ?

Comment: I uploaded it into the google drive. this is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBotKL5BjG609O58aefkEgNYHQ52U8Tt/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone through with your code , and find an issue which is causing the problem.

In your editform.jsp:- You have written this "userNname", this is worng

```
User Name:<input type="text" name="userNname" value="<%= m.getUserName()%>"/>
```

Use this : (it search for same name)

```
User Name:<input type="text" name="userName" value="<%= m.getUserName()%>"/>
```

Change "userNname" with "userName", it will work.Thanks